# OS X 10.11.1: XQuartz won't start

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, xquartz

Just upgraded my MacBook Pro from 10.10 to 10.11, and X11 (XQuartz, actually) stopped working: starts, but quits without visible effect or complaint.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out, quartz-wm (mentioned in my ~/.xinitrc) has moved from `/usr/X11R6/bin/quartz-wm` to `/usr/X11/bin/quartz-wm`.